# Where is my visual web developer template?

Tags: visual-studio

Today I installed Microsoft Visual web developer express on my system through Microsoft Web platform installer,and it installed successfully.
Now,the problem is that,I don't see any template available in File->New Website section.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try repairing the installation using the control panel -> add/remove programs applet? You may also want to try running VS with administrative privilages.

**Update:**
Try running  "devenv /resetsettings" from the command line. If that doesn't work, try deleting the following registry key.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio`